# Weblogic is serving war file but not listed in deployment list

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, war, weblogic12c

I have Weblogic12c installed on Red Hat.

When I want to deploy the new version of the application in Weblogic Server,
normally I delete the old war file and deploy the new one. This time when I deleted the old war file, everything was OK, but since deploying the new war file, Weblogic says that `context root is existing`. Now the war file is serving on Weblogic and I can call my APIs, but the war file is not shown on the deployment list, and I cannot delete it.

I restarted Weblogic several times but no changes occurred.

I think Weblogic is reading the war file from the cache. Now how can I delete my old war file and deploy the new version?

Comment: Did yçou undeploy your previous version with a tool like the admin console or WLST or did you just remove the file ?

Comment: no, the file name not shown on the console, deployment list

Comment: so you can stop your server and remove the tmp folder under $DOMAIN_HOME/servers/[server name]/tmp